# How do I place text specifically the word "Or" in-between these options?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a calculator that pushes out these options from input fields. How do I add the word "or" in between each displayed option? Here is the specific code that i am trying to modify.

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <div style="height: 100px;">
      <h2>FOAM DENSITY</h2>
      <select id="density" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" >
         <option value="standard">Standard (1.75 lbs per cubic feet)</option>
         <option value="open">Open Cell (0.75 lbs per cubic feet)</option>
         <option value="high">High (2.8 lbs per cubic feet)</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div  style="height: 100px;">
      <h2>FOAM THICKNESS</h2>
      <input id="thickness" name="thickness" type="text" placeholder="Inches" style="display: inline-block;float:right;"/>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 100px;">
      <h2>SQUARE FOOTAGE</h2>
      <input id="area" name="area" type="text" placeholder="Square Feet" style="display: inline-block;float:right;"/>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 100px;transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;" align="center">
      <button id ="calc" onclick="calc()" >Calculate</button>
   </div>
   <div id="opn" style="display: none">
      <p id="sys31"></p>
      <p id="sys100"></p>
   </div>
   <div id="stndrd" style="display: none">
      <p id="sys1"></p>
      <p id="sys9"></p>
      <p id="sys15"></p>
      <p id="sys50"></p>
   </div>
   <div id="hgh" style="display: none">
      <p id="sys10">h</p>
      <p id="sys33">h</p>
   </div>
   <style>
      h2{
      color:#3a55a7;display: inline-block;float:left;line-height: 0;
      }
      input[type=text]{
      width: 200px;height: 35%;padding-left: 15px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.00); border-radius: 5px; border-color:#f21d28;border-style:solid;font-family:'Nexa';text-transform:uppercase;line-height: 10px;outline: none;
      }
      select{
      height: 35%;font-family: 'Nexa'; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.00); border-radius: 5px;border-color:#f21d28;outline: none; border-style:solid; border-width: 2px;
      }
      #calc{
      background-color: #f21d28;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;font-size: 16px;text-transform:uppercase; font-family:'Nexa'; display: block; border-radius: 5px; letter-spacing: 2px;-webkit-transition: background-color .25s;transition: background-color .25s;transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;outline: none;
      }
      #calc:hover{
      color: #f21d28;background-color: #fff;
      } 
   </style>
   <script>
      function calc(){
        document.getElementById("opn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("stndrd").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hgh").style.display = "none";
        var den = document.getElementById("density").value;
        var thck = document.getElementById("thickness").value;
        var area = document.getElementById("area").value;
        var totalarea = area * thck;
        if(den == "open"){
            var sys31 = parseFloat(totalarea / 380).toFixed(2);
            var sys100 = parseFloat(totalarea / 1200).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("sys31").innerHTML = "System 31 Kits: "+sys31;
            document.innerHTML = "or";
            document.getElementById("sys100").innerHTML ="System 100 Kits: "+sys100;
            document.getElementById("opn").style.display = "block";
        }
        else if(den == "standard"){
            var sys1 = parseFloat(totalarea / 12).toFixed(2);
            var sys9 = parseFloat(totalarea / 108).toFixed(2);
            var sys15 = parseFloat(totalarea / 200).toFixed(2);
            var sys50 = parseFloat(totalarea / 600).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("sys1").innerHTML = "System I Kits: "+sys1;
            document.getElementById("sys9").innerHTML = "System 9 Kits: "+sys9;
            document.getElementById("sys15").innerHTML = "System 15 Kits: "+sys15;
            document.getElementById("sys50").innerHTML = "System 50 Kits: "+sys50;
            document.getElementById("stndrd").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            var sys10 = parseFloat(totalarea / 120).toFixed(2);
            var sys33 = parseFloat(totalarea / 396).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("sys10").innerHTML = "System 10 Kits: "+sys10;
            document.getElementById("sys33").innerHTML = "System 33 Kits: "+sys33;
            document.getElementById("hgh").style.display = "block";
        }
      }
   </script>
</div>
```

On the front-end I am just trying to show on screen the word or in between the listed results so currently it is like this.

```
System I Kits
System 9 Kits 
System 15 Kits
System 50 Kits
```

Id like it to display like this

```
System I Kits 
or 
System 9 Kits
or 
System 15 Kits 
or 
System 50 Kits
```

It currently displays vertically.

Comment: Perhaps you should provided the current result and the desired result. Currently, it is quite hard to decipher what you mean.

Comment: On the frontend im just trying to show on screen the word or in between the listed results so currently it look like this.
System I Kits
System 9 Kits
System 15 Kits
System 50 Kits

Id like it to display like this 
System I Kits
or
System 9 Kits
or
System 15 Kits
or
System 50 Kits

It currently displays vertically

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML code please?

Comment: @JackBashford I updated as you requested

Comment: @PatrickQ does my question make sense now?

Comment: @UserEnvy No, it doesn't.  You still haven't provided the HTML that you currently have, and the HTML that you want as a result.  All you did was add more Javascript.

Comment: @PatrickQ Please take a look now - I'm looking for what code I need to add to the javascript to get the result of the word "Or" separating each result. Again currently it displays the results on separate lines vertically we need to simply add the word OR on its own line in between each result.

Comment: @UserEnvy This doesn't seem like a Javascript issue at all.  Can't you just add `<p>OR</p>` between each of the lines in the HTML?

Comment: @PatrickQ No as the script actually displays a calculated result so added the tag as you suggested in the html didn't work that's what lead me to believe and after testing that we have to add the necessary code for "or" in the script.

Comment: @UserEnvy Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your attempt that you are saying did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue with the following html

```
<div style="width: 100%">
<div style="height: 100px;">
    <h2>FOAM DENSITY</h2><select id="density" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" >
        <option value="standard">Standard (1.75 lbs per cubic feet)</option>
        <option value="open">Open Cell (0.75 lbs per cubic feet)</option>
        <option value="high">High (2.8 lbs per cubic feet)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div  style="height: 100px;">
    <h2>FOAM THICKNESS</h2><input id="thickness" name="thickness" type="text" placeholder="Inches" style="display: inline-block;float:right;"/>
</div>
<div style="height: 100px;">
    <h2>SQUARE FOOTAGE</h2><input id="area" name="area" type="text" placeholder="Square Feet" style="display: inline-block;float:right;"/>
</div>
<div style="height: 100px;transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;" align="center">
    <button id ="calc" onclick="calc()" >Calculate</button>
</div>
<div id="opn" style="display: none">
    <p id="sys31"></p>
    <p class="or_space">OR</p>
    <p id="sys100"></p>
</div>
<div id="stndrd" style="display: none">
    <p id="sys1"></p>
    <p class="or_space">OR</p>
    <p id="sys9"></p>
    <p class="or_space">OR</p>
    <p id="sys15"></p>
    <p class="or_space">OR</p>
    <p id="sys50"></p>
</div>
<div id="hgh" style="display: none">
    <p id="sys10">h</p>
    <p class="or_space">OR</p>
    <p id="sys33">h</p>
</div>  
<style>
    h2{
        color:#3a55a7;display: inline-block;float:left;line-height: 0;
    }
    input[type=text]{
        width: 200px;height: 35%;padding-left: 15px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.00); border-radius: 5px; border-color:#f21d28;border-style:solid;font-family:'Nexa';text-transform:uppercase;line-height: 10px;outline: none;
    }
    select{
        height: 35%;font-family: 'Nexa'; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.00); border-radius: 5px;border-color:#f21d28;outline: none; border-style:solid; border-width: 2px;
    }
    #calc{
        background-color: #f21d28;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;font-size: 16px;text-transform:uppercase; font-family:'Nexa'; display: block; border-radius: 5px; letter-spacing: 2px;-webkit-transition: background-color .25s;transition: background-color .25s;transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;outline: none;
    }
    #calc:hover{
        color: #f21d28;background-color: #fff;
    }
    .or_space{
        margin: -10px 0 5px 0;            
    }
</style>
<script>
    function calc() {
        document.getElementById("opn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("stndrd").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hgh").style.display = "none";
        var den = document.getElementById("density").value;
        var thck = document.getElementById("thickness").value;
        var area = document.getElementById("area").value;
        var totalarea = area * thck;
        if (den == "open") {
            var sys31 = parseFloat(totalarea / 380).toFixed(2);
            var sys100 = parseFloat(totalarea / 1200).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("sys31").innerHTML = "System 31 Kits: " + sys31;
            document.innerHTML = "or";
            document.getElementById("sys100").innerHTML = "System 100 Kits: " + sys100;
            document.getElementById("opn").style.display = "block";
        } else if (den == "standard") {
            var sys1 = parseFloat(totalarea / 12).toFixed(2);
            var sys9 = parseFloat(totalarea / 108).toFixed(2);
            var sys15 = parseFloat(totalarea / 200).toFixed(2);
            var sys50 = parseFloat(totalarea / 600).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("sys1").innerHTML = "System I Kits: " + sys1;
            document.getElementById("sys9").innerHTML = "System 9 Kits: " + sys9;
            document.getElementById("sys15").innerHTML = "System 15 Kits: " + sys15;
            document.getElementById("sys50").innerHTML = "System 50 Kits: " + sys50;
            document.getElementById("stndrd").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            var sys10 = parseFloat(totalarea / 120).toFixed(2);
            var sys33 = parseFloat(totalarea / 396).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("sys10").innerHTML = "System 10 Kits: " + sys10;
            document.getElementById("sys33").innerHTML = "System 33 Kits: " + sys33;
            document.getElementById("hgh").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you everyone for attempting to help.